# How to prevent a label from causing the whole layout to resize

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout

I have a following Qt code:

```
QVBoxLayout* box = new QVBoxLayout;
label = new QLabel(); // will be set later dynamically
box->addWidget (label);
```

Text in label will be set later.
The problem is that when label resizes, it resizes QVBoxLayout, and it resizes other neighboring widgets.
I don't want to make a label or layout fixed width. Because I want them to resize with a whole window.

Is it possible to tell a widget to take all the place that it has in a layout, but not more?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to modify the [size policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) of widgets? You can accomplish what you want with this.

Here are all size policies: [QSizePolicy — enum QSizePolicy::Policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum)

Answer (score 0):

You can either set a [maximumSize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#maximumSize-prop) or have a look at [sizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the stretch factor ([setStrechFactor](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qboxlayout.html#setStretchFactor)) for the main window you are placing the layout.

Comment: setting the stretch factor to 0 means that the layout stretch is auto calculated according to the other widgets. for example if you have a pushbutton and a label in a layout and set the stretch factor to 0 for each element, then the size for each widget is auto assigned. if you set 100;1; as a stretch factor, there will be a 100 proportion for the widgets' sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a look at the following methods :

- [`void setScaledContents(bool)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop)
- [`void setWordWrap(bool on)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlabel.html#wordWrap-prop)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the label to fill the space of one line all the time, if the text is just one line, then the solution would simply be:

```cpp
QVBoxLayout* box = new QVBoxLayout;  
label = new QLabel(" "); // The space will create a vertical space in the layout  
box->addWidget (label);
```

The "empty" label will now behave exactly as it will after you set the text.